# Slow insert in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, insert

Our products' database contains an audit trail table:

```
CREATE TABLE gn_AuditTable(
  gn_ObjectId int NULL,
  gn_Action smallint NULL,
  gn_Time datetime NULL,
  gn_UserId int NULL,
  gn_Login varbinary(16) NULL,
  gn_ExtraObjectId int NULL,
  gn_ExtraInfo int NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

We add rows to this table with a simple `insert` statement - no stored procedures:

```
insert into gn_AuditTable (
  gn_ObjectId,gn_Time,gn_UserId,gn_Login,gn_Action,gn_ExtraObjectId,gn_ExtraInfo
) values (
  ?,?,?,?,?,?,?
)
```

passing the values of the columns as parameters to the query; there are also no triggers.

The problem is that sometimes this insert is super-slow - taking in some cases more than 30 seconds and timing-out.

We have multiple installations of the same product, and we are experienceing the problem in some - but not all - of them.

The audit table can be quite big - up to some million of rows. The very slow insert happens with databases that have big tables (quite naturally) - but we have other databases with simliar number of rows that run fine, and even the databases experiencing the problem have it intermittently, in most cases the insert is reasonably fast (sub-second).

The table has 6 non-clustered, non-unique indexes:

- `gn_Login`;
- `gn_ObjectId`;
- `gn_Action` and `gn_ExtraInfo`;
- `gn_ExtraObjectId`;
- `gn_Time`;
- `gn_UserId`.

Having all these indexes could cause the problem, but again, we have the same indexes everywhere and the problem only somewhere / sometimes.

We had the insert timing-out at least once on a test database with only one user, so the problem does not appear to be related to the overall load but to the insert and the table themselves.

We used to have a clustered index on `gn_ObjectId`, but we got rid of it as an attempt to solve this problem. `gn_ObjectId` is not sequential and so we thought that it is a poor choice for a clustered index, forcing SQL Server to re-order rows on inserts. Probably `gn_Time` - that is always increasing - would be a better choice.

There is no primary key because there is no column or combination of columns that  is 'naturally' unique - we would have to add an id column, and it seems just overhead.

Does anyone have any suggestion at what we could look at to diagnose the problem? What is an `insert` doing that can take so much time - intermittently?

Comment: Based on my very lightweight understanding of the internals stuff, for each insert you're doing into `gn_AuditTable` you're having 6 additional insert operations to keep those indexes up to date. 7 writes that all have to succeed or fail together. Do you have any idea whether those indexes are even being used? SQL Server does, see this [article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/08/SQL-Server---Find-missing-and-unused-indexes.aspx) from Mladen

Comment: Thanks @billinkc. Yes, those indexes have been added (over time) to speed up various queries the system does - based on query execution plans returned by SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem:

- there is a maintenance procedure that removes data from the database, including rows from `gn_AuditTable`;
- the `delete gn_AuditTable . .` is in a transaction together with other statements (bad)
- it can happen that quite a lot of rows are deleted in one go - in such a case SQL Server locks the entire table - and then `insert gn_AuditTable` time-out waiting for the transaction to finish

We discovered this because we were able to have a look at the locks when we got a time-out, and we noticed the table lock. We are moving the `delete gn_AuditTable . . .` out of the transaction, and possible split it into smaller batches, not to trigger a table lock.

We are implementing a clustered index on `gn_Time` and the Instant File Initialization - both are beneficial independently from this specific problem  - thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Why no clustered index? Why no primary key?

This is most likely your problem: you don't have any *order* to the table (in the sense of, say, an IDENTITY column) this you are inserting into a heap

See

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5094400/27535 (SO)
- http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/08/14/are-inserts-quicker-to-heap-or-clustered-tables.aspx (Tibor Karaszi)

Edit, after update.

Having a non-unique clustered index requires a [uniquifier (DBA.se links)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniquifier) per duplicate gn_ObjectId entry. This is not a good clustering key, which is best when it is

- numeric
- monotonically increasing
- narrow

I also assume you haven't tried a IDENTITY column then...? Try it, report back..

Edit 2, as @JNK says, an ID column is not an overhead in this situation because of how your writes will be managed on disk

Comment: Thanks. I am editing my question to answer your questions...

Comment: FYI, ID columns aren't "just overhead" - they work well for situations like this where you have no other unique identifier per row.

Comment: Plus note that all of the fields are nullable.  Good times.

Comment: @BrentOzar: sorry, I don't understand your comment. Is there a possible relation between the columns being nullable and the `insert` time?

Comment: @JNK: 'overhead' in the sense that it would be a column that is never read nor referened anywhere

Comment: @MiMo it's another red flag for a design issue.  And it's OK that the ID field isn't referenced, since it guarantees your inserts are ordered, and makes lookups quicker and all your NC indexes smaller since you have a narrow key to reference

Comment: @MiMo No, no, I just meant that clearly there's no thought to the database design.  If you're only worried about insert speed, lose the non-clustered indexes.  If you're worried about both insert and select speeds, you need to define a clustered index, set the non-nullability appropriately and decide which indexes you really need. 6 NCLs means you're writing 6 copies of the table.  Plus, are you doing any updates? Have you read up on the forwarded record problem?

Comment: @BrentOzar: geeh, thanks for that... I did most of the design of that db. There are no updates, we do a bunch of different selects - hence those indexes.

Comment: @MiMo Doh! Hey, at least you're in a good place - you're asking for help. So first, put a clustered index on an identity field. The page you want to insert into will always be in memory (unlike a heap, which will be inserting all over the place). Set fields as non-nullable if they're required, and try to minimize the number of indexes to cut down on insert speed.

Answer (score 6):

Is your database large enough? Are you sure your INSERT don't trigger auto-growth? If your deployements don't have [Instant File Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx) enabled then this is exactly the behavior one would expect when a database file growth is triggered: random blocking of writes for the duration of file growth and initialization. You could also be experiencing log file growth (this at least can eb quickly identified by looking at the [Log Growths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189883.aspx) performance counter) but for log growths to occur you need to have a non-simple recovery model and a backup strategy that is basically absent (ie. log truncation does not occur).

As for the design of your table: time series are usually clustered by the time value, because most queries cover time ranges (eg. 'select all events in the past 3 days') so that would make `gn_Time` your likely non-unique clustered key candidate.

Comment: +1 Should have noted this myself (as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/2009693/27535) Could by a regular or auto shrink going on, for example

Comment: Thanks. Log files are trucated regularly, but a growth of the data file is indeed possible. My understanding though was that the operation on the data files are done by the lazy writer, and so they don't block the query - only the writes to the log are synchronous. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MiMo: you are wrong unfortunately. The lazy writer is tasked with flushing dirty pages, [something completely different](http://youtu.be/Tym0MObFpTI). A database growth event is a big freeze on the database, all queries and all writes are blocked until the file is grown *and initialized*.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it - we'll go and check file growth.